# Unable to create xaml file in Xamarin named "PasswordRecovery"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms

Guy's I am trying to add a xaml file in my PLC as a view (PAGE) for which I am putting name as ***PasswordRecovery***.xaml but My visual studio is asking me access denied admin access required..

Can I know Why we need Admin access to create a simple xaml file in visual studio??
However generally we can create any xaml file with the different name not required admin access??

For more details please go through the attach !
I Just wanted to know the reason.[image]

Comment: It is kind of weird, although I do see that your Visual Studio is not running as Administrator, which can cause some trouble. Shut down your Visual Studio, right-click the icon and select 'Run as administrator', see if that helps. To always run it as administrator, go into the options and find the checkbox to enable this option.